# I'm trying to learn SQLite for Python...Best method?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've read a few books that touch on SQLite but nothing concrete enough to help me learn it within Python, Question is, is there any book or source you could recommend to help me with this...

Secondly is learning MySQL the same as learning SQLite because I see those resources everywhere...

Comment: You sound confused. "MySQL", "mSQL", and "SQLite" are three different programs.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are unrelated programs. Why do you want to learn SQL?

Comment: [This is MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/). [This is SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: That is the `SQLite` comes with Python: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to learn about [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), variants of which are used by a number of different relational databases, including [MySQL](http://mysql.com/) and [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) (which as several comments have pointed out you are mixing together) using the python standard library's [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module. You can't go wrong with Doug Hellmann's PyMOTW introduction to the `sqlite3` module: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/sqlite3/.

Comment: Generous answer, zeekay, thanks for speaking to the gist of the question with a helpful solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just as zeekay said, MySQL and SQLite are two different relational databases. They can work independently without support of Python.  For example, you can use command console or firefox sqlite plugin to manipulate sqlite database. I guess what you want to learn is the python API how to manipulate sqlite. I would recommend [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) as the first choice. It follows the DB-API2 interface and easy to learn. And as soon as you understand how to use connection and cursor class, you can do a lot of things with sqlite.